# How to fix the jQuery issue in my code

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm new to stakoverflow. I'm working on a custom PHP code (editing previously done page by some coder). I want the "Click me for a popup!" text to popup a jquery window.

I used the same code here.

http://www.rivalhost.com/stopthehacker/test.php

But in the following page, it doesn't work. 
http://www.rivalhost.com/stopthehacker/home.php

I understand there is some jQuery conflict in the page. But I couldn't find it. Please help.

Thanks in advance,
Sampath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the script for the countdown function.

```
Error: TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function
Source File: http://www.rivalhost.com/stopthehacker/js/home-slider.js
```

In your code you are calling a function called countdown, but that function does not exist. You need to include the library or script file that contains that function. That will at least get rid of that error and allow the rest of the script to continue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this. Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/qkram/

```
$("a.clickMe").on("click", function(e) {
        $("body").append('<div class="modalOverlay">');
// To Load the Popupbox
      $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");

});

$('#popupBoxClose').click( function() {         
        $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
       $(".modalOverlay").remove(); 
});
```

Comment: I added this to the code now. Please check. But somehow, it is not working.

Comment: Go to the fiddle link i have given. There is the HTML and CSS code as well. In order to make it work properly, you should add the complete code. Also, when you say its not working, try giving your code as well.

Comment: have you written the css as well ?